# Go web application with a mock user repository

Tags: beginner, go, http, server

I'm new to go and struggling to create structure of web application. I read about clean architecture and Ben Johnsons [blog post about package layout](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1). Now i want to put it all together. This is just scratch. Service abstraction looks redundant but in real project there will be services that contains more than one repository. What is your opinion in structuring project like this? And how i bootstrap it together.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

type user struct {
    name string
}

type userRepository interface {
    getByID(id int) (*user, error)
}

type userService struct {
    userRepository userRepository
}

func (us *userService) findUser(id int) (*user, error) {
    return us.userRepository.getByID(id)
}

type mockUserRepo struct{}

func (mr *mockUserRepo) getByID(id int) (*user, error) {
    return &user{"John Doe"}, nil
}

type safeHandlerFunc func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) error

type mainHandler struct {
    //session
    //logger
    view *template.Template
}

func (h *mainHandler) handle(sh safeHandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("x-custom-header", "random")
        if err := sh(w, r); err != nil {
            //return some error view
            //log error
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }
}

type userHandler struct {
    *mainHandler
    userService *userService
}

func (uh *userHandler) getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (err error) {
    sid := r.URL.Query().Get("user_id")
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(sid)
    if err == nil {
        return
    }

    u, err := uh.userService.findUser(id)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    return uh.view.ExecuteTemplate(w, "user.gohtml", u)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting web server...")

    mock := new(mockUserRepo)

    h := &mainHandler{
        view: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("views/*")),
    }
    uh := &userHandler{h, &userService{mock}}

    http.HandleFunc("/", uh.handle(uh.getUser))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To really understand the blog post, I recommend looking at its example project (https://github.com/benbjohnson/wtf - see also `http` branch).

Ben Johnsons posted another post detailing its steps: https://medium.com/wtf-dial/wtf-dial-domain-model-9655cd523182).

Regarding the organization of your code, it would be like this:

```
project.go // the exported interfaces
mock/      // the mock implementations
http/      // http handler/server
mysql/     // the mysql implementations
cmd/       // the 'glue'
```

**A major point is that you can only import parent (sub)packages.**
For instance your `http` subpackage can not depend on the `mysql` subpackage (`http` should only depend on the interfaces defined in `project.go` - `project.UserService` for instance).

The only exception to this rule is your `main.go` (or your tests).
For instance, you import `project/http` and `project/mysql` and connect them :

Since the `mysql.UserService struct` implements the `project.UserService interface` it is transparent for the `http` package which expects a `project.UserService interface`

---

### `project.go`

*take a look at https://github.com/benbjohnson/wtf/blob/http/wtf.go*

```
package project

type UserID int

type User struct {
    Name string
}

type UserService interface {
    GetByID(UserID) (*User, error)
}

// HTTPService is similar
```

---

### `mock/user.go`

*take a look at https://github.com/benbjohnson/wtf/blob/http/mock/mock.go*

```
package mock

import (
    "your/project"
)

type UserService struct {
    GetByIDFn      func(id project.UserID) *project.User, error
    GetByIDInvoked bool
}

func (s *UserService) GetByID(id project.UserID) (*project.User, error) {
    s.GetByIDInvoked = true
    return s.GetByIDFn(id)
}
```

---

### `mysql/user.go`

Your actual implementation with a MySQL database for instance (adapt to your own user backend)

---

### `http/*.go`

*take a look at https://github.com/benbjohnson/wtf/tree/6d855c355488361b22b1a5ba13d9453e39141292/http*

```
package http

import (
    "your/project"
    "net/http"
)

type HTTPService struct {
    // Here you embed some UserService Interface
    UserService project.UserService
}

func (h *HTTPService) HandleHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Use the UserService Interface (don't care if it's mock or real)
    h.UserService.GetByID(...)
    // write response
}
```

---

### `cmd/mocked/main.go`

Glue everything (be careful of import names conflicts!):

```
package main

import (
    "your/project/http"
    nethttp "net/http"
)

func main(){
    server := http.HTTPService{
        UserService: mock.UserService{},
    }

    nethttp.ListenAndServe(":8888", server)
}
```